# Custom GROK filter - Logstash -> Elasticsearch

Tags: regex, elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok

I have a log which is getting captured and sent to logstash, the format of the log is

```
22304999    5   400.OUTPUT_SERVICE.510  submit  The limit has been exceeded. Please use a different option. 2.54.44.221 /api/output/v3/contract/:PCID/order /api/output/v3/contract/:pcid/order https://www.example.org/output/ PUT 400 2017-09-28T15:50:57.843176Z
```

I am trying to create a custom grok filter to add the header fields before it gets sent to elasticsearch.

My aim is something like this,

```
 SessionID   => "22304999"
 HitNumber   => "5"
 FactValue   => "400.OUTPUT_SERVICE.510"
 DimValue1   => "submit"
 ErrMessage  => "The limit has been exceeded. Please use a different option."
 IP          => "2.54.44.221"
 TLT_URL     => "/api/output/v3/contract/:PCID/order"
 URL         => "/api/output/v3/contract/:pcid/order"
 Refferer    => "https://www.example.org/output/"
 Method      => "PUT"
 StatsCode   => "400"
 ReqTime     => "2017-09-28T15:50:57.843176Z"
```

I am new to this so only trying to understand how I apply and test this, for example I would start with an empty filter,

```
filter {
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "" }
   }
 }
```

My first question is `match => { "message" => "" }` is message just a log line? What defines 'message'?

My log and the fields I want are separated by a Tab, after each Tab its a new field, would this make what I am trying to achieve easier, rather than looking for a pattern can I just look for the next Tab?

Failing this, could someone provide an example for one of my fields, from that I should be able to complete the rest.

Comment: You mean something like this https://regex101.com/r/SUCH7X/1

Comment: Haha what a guy! I wanted somethings explaining but that page also does that! (?<SessionID> is how I define a group? Excellent!! thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regex**: `(?<SessionID>\S+)\s+(?<HitNumber>\S+)\s+(?<FactValue>\S+)\s+(?<DimValue1>\S+)\s+(?<ErrMessage>.+)\s+(?<IP>(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3})\s+(?<TLT_URL>\S+)\s+(?<URL>\S+)\s+(?<Refferer>\S+)\s+(?<Method>\S+)\s+(?<StatsCode>\S+)\s+(?<ReqTime>\S+)`

**Details**:

- `(?<>)` Named Capture Group
- `\S` matches any non-whitespace character
- `\d` Matches a digit, `{n,m}` Matches between `n` and `m` times
- `+` Matches between one and unlimited times

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SUCH7X/2)

**Output**:

```
{
  "SessionID": [
    [
      "22304999"
    ]
  ],
  "HitNumber": [
    [
      "5"
    ]
  ],
  "FactValue": [
    [
      "400.OUTPUT_SERVICE.510"
    ]
  ],
  "DimValue1": [
    [
      "submit"
    ]
  ],
  "ErrMessage": [
    [
      "The limit has been exceeded. Please use a different option."
    ]
  ],
  "IP": [
    [
      "2.54.44.221"
    ]
  ],
  "TLT_URL": [
    [
      "/api/output/v3/contract/:PCID/order"
    ]
  ],
  "URL": [
    [
      "/api/output/v3/contract/:pcid/order"
    ]
  ],
  "Refferer": [
    [
      "https://www.example.org/output/"
    ]
  ],
  "Method": [
    [
      "PUT"
    ]
  ],
  "StatsCode": [
    [
      "400"
    ]
  ],
  "ReqTime": [
    [
      "2017-09-28T15:50:57.843176Z"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you, could you explain how this would fit into filter {
   grok {
     match => { "message" => "" }
   }
 }

Comment: Shorten all `[^\s]` to `\S`

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing a solution, you can always use this site:

> http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match

I made this grok pattern for your problem:

```
%{INT:SessionID}\s*%{INT:HitNumber}\s*%{NOTSPACE:FaceValue}\s*%{GREEDYDATA:ErrMessage}\s*%{IP:IP}\s*%{NOTSPACE:TLT_URL}\s*%{NOTSPACE:URL}\s*%{NOTSPACE:Referer}\s*%{NOTSPACE:Method}\s*%{INT:StatsCode}\s*%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:ReqTime}
```

Comment: Ahh this is much more like what I was expecting so see, I am right in thinking to allow this for logstash I can do filter { grok { match => { "message" => "GROK PATTERN HERE" } } }?